# Bounding rect of HTML element within scrolling element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm interested in getting the bounding rect of a HTML element within an scrolling (`overflow:auto`) div container. I've tried `getBoundingClientRect()` but this is always relative to the window. A `DOMRect` is not needed, I just wanna know the width of the viewport and the position of the element.

So for me the only solution seems to be to subtract the rect of the scrolling div. But this could get complicated as my final use case is working with shadow DOM and custom components.

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100px;position:absolute;top:50px;">
  <div id="elem">
    some content
  </div>
  <div style="height:100px;">
    ignore
  </div>
  <div>
    ignore
  </div>
  <div>
    ignore
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  window.alert("top="+document.getElementById("elem").getBoundingClientRect().top);
</script>
```

In this example you can see the outer most div has `overflow` set but the bounding rect does not show 0 before scrolling but 50.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nvemtoyk/

Comment: The minimal code to reproduce your problem needs to be contained directly in your question (in text form and properly formatted; as a stack snippet when applicable), do not just dump it onto an external platform. please. [mre]

Comment: edited my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround but with some caveats. First, you have to traverse all parent elements until you find the viewport. Secondy, It's only working if the overflow div was already scrolled.

At least in my case the second is true because the `overflow` style is not visible in javascript at my custom element. Maybe in "legacy" HTML this is not the case.

```js
  getViewport(elem) {
    // root element
    if (elem === document.body) {
      return document.documentElement;
    }
    // scrolling element (only working if already scrolled)
    // maybe elem.style.overflow is available, but not in my case
    else if (elem.scrollLeft > 0 || elem.scrollTop > 0) {
      return elem;
    }
    // traverse
    else {
      return getViewport(elem.offsetParent);
    }
  }

  getBoundingRect(element, viewport) {
    // root element
    if (viewport === document.documentElement) {
      return element.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
    // relative to viewport
    else {
      var elRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      var vpRect = viewport.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        bottom: elRect.bottom - vpRect.top,
        height: elRect.height,
        left: elRect.left - vpRect.left,
        right: elRect.right - vpRect.left,
        top: elRect.top - vpRect.top,
        width: elRect.width
      };
    }
  }
```